# Any way to make dialogs appear/disappear with a transition in MFC?

Tags: mfc, winapi, transition

For instance I have a main dialog, when I click a button a smaller dialog appears next to it. But it would be neat if the small one could somehow transition in, rather than simply appear. For instance using transparency, or zooming in, or sliding in from width=0 -> full-width.

Making an actual dialog do such things isn't too hard, but what about the controls within it? How might we approach this in a way that is reusable on different dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any MFC libraries that do this. Closest is AnimateWindow(). Depending on how flashy you want to make your effects, this may or may not be enough (e.g. a simple fade in you can do with AnimateWindow()).